# C# Webapi PDF creation with header, footer and pagination

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

What I want to do is to create a PDF of a invoice. Now I have a webapi server with a get method that returns all the data I need to show in the invoice.

The first approach I have tried is to create the HTML of the invoice and convert it to PDF. The problem with this approach are the header, footer and pagination in HTML (every sheet of the invoice must show the logo and address and the footer must sum the amounts page by page). My first question is: is there a simple way to do this in HTML before converting it to PDF?

The other approach I have tried is to use Crystal Reports (maybe SQL Reporting Services would be better, I do not know) to create a report and use it to create the PDF, but maybe it is overkilled once I already have all the data calculated from the webapi. My second question is: can this kind of report designers use the data I already have calculated? Or do they always read from database again?

I am not asking for recommendations or suggestions, it is not a subjective question, I just want answer to those two objective questions.

Thank you

Comment: use a third party nuget package like PDFNet, IronPDF. There are a lot others. Search google.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany, I have searched a lot in Google, and everywhere there are problems with pagination, headers and footer. I think none of these two packages you have said are able to do this properly

Comment: Try Spire.PDF. It supports pagination https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncfusion's PDF component is free if your annual revenue is less than $1M.
Here's the user manual section dealing with PDF headers/Footers:
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-headers-and-footers

But if your layout is beyond rudimentary, you might end up wasting time tweaking things.  Consider dumping the data into a table dedicated for this process, And use Crystal Reports to design a report against that table. You can then easily export to PDF while ensuring easy future tweaks to layout and functionality.